# Microsoft Access 2010 file viewer

Tags: microsoft-access

Years ago, I was able to make an Access database and then give it to clients and they could open it up and make changes (via forms).  If I'm remembering right, they didn't need to have Access on their machine at all, but I might be confused.

I know that there are viewers for Word, but is there anything like that for Access 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [Package Solution Wizard](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/package-solution-wizard-overview-HA010294985.aspx), which can be installed by modifying your office installation (if it is not already installed), is the tool you need.

It is not a viewer, but a tool for packaging your application for your clients.

From the linked page:

> The Package Solution Wizard provides a simple way to bundle and deploy Microsoft Access database applications.

You will also need the [Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=57A350CD-5250-4DF6-BFD1-6CED700A6715&displaylang=en):

> You can include the Access Runtime in the installation packages of Access applications so that these applications can be deployed and used on computers where Access is not installed.

The runtime provides all the Access resources you clients will need to run your application.